# Field growing when text incoming

Tags: powerapps

I have a datacard with a HTML text in it. I use this label to trace activities on my form. I want to label to grow when I add too much text.

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `AutoHeight` property of the HTML Text control, and if it's inside a data card (in a form), it will grow to fit the content inside of it, and the containing data card will also grow accordingly. See the screen capture below for an example (the border shows the limits of the data card).

[image: Growing HTML Text control]